# Custom column using not displayed field (but available in CDS)

Tags: odata, sapui5, cds

I've created a list report, to which I've extended by adding some custom columns. The problem I'm facing is that my custom columns only work when the CDS field behind it (bind) is being displayed at the standard columns.

I.e

```
<Column id="ExtensionWizard::Attachments" xmlns="sap.ui.table" width="3em">
...
  <Button icon="{= ${dmsDocumentCount} === 0 ? 'sap-icon://warning' : 'sap-icon://attachment' }" 
     xmlns="sap.m" press="onDisplayAttachments"/>
...
</Column>
```

Displays this:

[image]

And only if I display the `dmsDocumentCount` column I have the desired output:

[image]

I could see that this happens because the oData service is not being requested to return the `dmsDocumentCount` field.

So your answer can go both ways:

How to force this field to be requested by the OData. Remember I'm extending a list report.
How to achieve the the result (or similar).
Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0):

In your `UI.LineItem` annotation you can add the `UI.Hidden` annotation term such as

```
<Record Type="UI.DataField">
    <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="dmsDocumentCount"/>
    <Annotation Term="UI.Hidden" Bool="true"/>
</Record>
```

The field will be requested but not shown in the table.

Comment: Didn't worked....
I can see the payload for all items except this one (that is hidden). In the CDS it is being exposed (with a position).

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your answer. Are you annotating the CDS in the backend or in a frontend annotation.xml file?

Comment: Sorry, in the CDS I've left the field just with UI.LineItem.position (tried without it too). I'm annotating in the front end. 
Could someone confirm that this works? I don't see why it wouldn't...started different projects from scratch with different ui5 versions and...still nothing. Either I get both at payload and list report or I don't get it at all...

Comment: Maybe you are implementing your extension in a wrong way... Take a look to this link (https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/22/how-to-use-smart-templates-with-sap-web-ide-extensibility/), in particular Step 4: it helped me a lot! Let e know if this link plus my previous suggestion works :)

Comment: You were right, the column extension was messed up. There was no reference to the  core:CustomData annotation, with the refference to the oData property. Fixing that made your original answer work!
Thanks a lot.